# How to detect browser FORWARD action alone in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events, popstate

How can I detect that the user has specifically clicked on the browser forward button (action)?

Like I want to block the browser forward action using the below code.

```
history.go(1);
```

But the back action needs to work with its default behavior.

During the Mount :

```
componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("popstate", this.onBackButtonEvent);
}
```

During unMount:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("popstate", this.onBackButtonEvent);
}
```

Now this listener function is getting triggered for browser **backward** and **forward** actions.

```
onBackButtonEvent = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();        
}
```

How to differentiate between browser **back** and **forward** actions like bank sites handle browser forward actions.